# which one is better way to approach ? Using PJSIP or SIP Android API to build SIP based calling app

Tags: java, android, sip, pjsip

I am not able to decide which one to go for implementing SIP based voice calling app in android.

Shall i use Android SIP API or go with PJSIP ? which one has successful implementation till now ? Please help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I will try to provide my two cents on this:

Android SIP Stack relays on an old [JAIN SIP](https://jsip.java.net/) version plus some extensions (IMS, supporting RTP, etc.). Main problem with this stack is that, in most devices, it only works via WiFi, no 3G or LTE (note that `android.net.sip.SipManager` contains method `isSipWifiOnly` to know if this limitation is enabled).

On the other hand, `pjsip` is quite complete, like they say, it's not a SIP stack but a full multimedia communications library. It's really versatile: you can use a huge number of configuration or just run it as a [simple user agent](http://svn.pjsip.org/repos/pjproject/trunk/pjsip-apps/src/samples/simple_pjsua.c). It works with any kind of data connection (not limited to WiFi).

Now the comparison: In my opinion, `pjsip` is more complete and versatile but more difficult to integrate with you project (with Android SIP Stack everything remains in the SDK environment while, with `pjsip`, you would need to use the NDK and a JNI library).

My opinion: If you plan to create a very simple SIP app and you don't mind the WiFi limitation, I think, the best would be using native SIP API but, if you plan to improve it and do something more "interesting", I would strongly recommend `pjsip`. I've used both JAIN SIP and `pjsip` and, again, my vote goes for `psip`. But this is just my opinion.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Does the last sentence "I've used both JAIN SIP and `pjsip` and, again, my vote goes for `psip`. But this is just my opinion." can be replaced by "I've used both JAIN SIP and `pjsip` and, again, my vote goes for `pjsip`. But this is just my opinion." ? :)